# How can I access files in my SRC folder?

Tags: java, image, null

Hi ive been trying to access image files from within my SRC folder so that I can run it directly from the jar. Unfortunatly its not loading them can I please have some help. Its a null pointer exception and cannot read input file. here is the location of the folder and what I put in the code. CODE: "/sprites/mapsheet2.png" Directory: C:\Users\Lucas\workspace\Vigilante\src\sprites\mapsheet2.png if any extra info is needed tell me and ill send it.

Comment: *any extra info* - Code Please.

Comment: *if any extra info is needed tell me and ill send it.* Put the relevant code instead of just explaining the problem.

Comment: The answers are all correct as far as they go, but I believe you may have a different problem.  When you build the jar file, does the build system _know_ that it needs to include those particular resources?  Usually the build system configuration will have options to specify what types of resources to include in the jar.

Comment: IS that where i set it as a source folder?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Answer (score 0):

Resources from .jar file can be loaded with: `getClass().getResource()`
 It returns URL with correct path

```
Image icon = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("image´s path"));
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
 at Graphics.spritesheet.<init>(spritesheet.java:21)
 at Tile.Tile.<init>(Tile.java:11)
 at Tiles.Wall.<init>(Wall.java:10)
 at Tiles.tiles.<init>(tiles.java:7)
 at Core.core.<init>(core.java:31)
 at Core.core.main(core.java:240)

Comment: Don't put output in a comment.  It is unreadable.  Instead [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17774984/edit) the question to include the output, and use code formatting on it.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Answer (score 0):

You can pack all required resources at the .jar archive file. And access it using

```
InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("res\file.img")
```

can use imageIO for converting to Image.

Comment: protected spritesheet s = new spritesheet("/sprites/Blocks.png");

Answer (score 0):

You could try to load the image as a ByteArrayInputStream, into a BufferedImage.  Something like this:
                      BufferedImage img = null;
                          try{
                        BufferedInputStream sc = new BufferedInputStream(ImageLoad.class.getResourceAsStream(file));
                    ArrayList in = new ArrayList();
                    byte b = null;
                    while((b = sc.read) != null)in.add(b);
                    byte[]
                    bytes = new byte[in.size()];
                    for(int i = 0; i < in.size(); i ++)bytes[i] = in.get(i);
                    img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
                    }catch(Exception e){}

and then just use the image as you need it!  The only thing is you have to have sprites/mapsheet2.png in the same folder as the class you are running it from.  Say your class is ImageLoad.java, ImageLoad.java would have to be in the same package as sprites/mapsheet2.png.  EC:

ImageLoad.java is in package image.load, in package image.load are the resources sprites(A Dir), and sprites/mapsheet2.png, and the same for any other images required to load in that area.  If you want to load the image and use it in another class, you could just create a method including the above code, and return a bufferedImage.  EC:

```
    public class ImageLoad {
       public static BufferedImage load(String file) throws Exception{
                BufferedInputStream sc = new BufferedInputStream(ImageLoad.class.getResourceAsStream(file));
                ArrayList<Byte> in = new ArrayList<Byte>();
                byte b = null;
                while((b = sc.read) != null)in.add(b);
                byte[]
                bytes = new byte[in.size()];                    
                for(int i = 0; i < in.size(); i ++)bytes[i] = in.get(i);
                return ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
                    }
               }
```

Comment: I dont think that the method is the error it read it perfectly fine before I tried to read it from the SRC

Comment: Hold on its fixed thank you all for your quick and reliable help. rbilliant community.